How can I become a UK Patent Attorney?
I have graduated from university with a Certificate of Higher Education (CertHE) in Computer Science (AI), have completed a short course in Explainable AI, and have 2-3 years of experience in IT and Technology. Among knowledge of other areas. How would i proceed to become a patent Attorney in the UK, and how much experience would I need before applying?
I have read some of the articles on IP Careers and contacted a recruitment agency, and they said they do not receive or advertise jobs suitable for candidates with limited experience in science, engineering, or AI, but said they will let me know if they are told to. I would like to know how much experience a person needs before becoming a Patent Attorney in the UK, and if there are any alternative routes into this career, other than studying for an undergraduate degree.

Perhaps you should look for a position as a trainee patent attorney, through other agencies, or professional journals. Cast your net wide. Related: How to become a patent attorney in 9 steps.

At the very least, don't be a Lawyer (who) Used ChatGPT In Court—And Cited Fake Cases. A Judge Is Considering Sanctions

When you say you are a "graduate of Computer Science", could you clarify what type of degree that is?

I graduated from university with a Certificate of Higher Education (CertHE) in Computer Science (AI).

I have been applying for positions as a trainee patent attorney, but would like to know what type of experience would be needed if I have not completed an undergraduate degree and how many years of experience would be needed.

As the link from Weather Vane in the comments explains (omitting a couple of optional steps):


Apply for a STEM-related degree

STEM degrees cover various specialisations, from general engineering
to computing or science-related qualifications. An undergraduate
degree is necessary to continue to a trainee patent attorney role with
eligibility for the certification and qualification process. For
example, a 2:1 degree in engineering may be vital in finding a trainee
role in a business that designs supercars and meets the eligibility
requirements to begin the patent attorney qualification process.

Find a job as a trainee patent attorney

Patents attorneys typically train on the job as trainee professionals.
Most businesses hire trainees in a kind of apprenticeship programme,
providing the mentorship and in-house support required to develop
skills. For example, if you're interested in working in a legal firm,
you may acquire a trainee role on the patent team with the support of
qualified patent attorneys to complete self-directed study and attend
external training courses. On-the-job learning is vital for patent
attorney positions to gain experience and understanding of each
sector.

Complete a foundation certificate

To qualify as a patent attorney, you first complete a foundation-level
certification. The Intellectual Property Regulation Board (IPRB)
regulates the IPReg-accredited Foundation Certificate, requiring
trainee patent attorneys to complete a course or pass an exam to
continue onto the next stage in their training. Whether trainees
complete final certificates depends on the needs of the employer.

Pass four final-level diploma examinations

Final diploma exams continue from the foundation certificate if your
employer requires it. In these exams, you cover various topics, such
as amendment of patent applications, drafting, intellectual property
law and assessment of patent validity. After completing these four
examinations, you've fulfilled the necessary academic processes to
become a patent attorney. Typically, your tests run alongside your
practice experience, though some people may complete certification
sooner.

Undertake two years of supervised practice

The final requirement to qualify as a patent attorney is completing
either two years of supervised experience or four years of
unsupervised experience in a junior or trainee patent attorney role.
For supervised experience to apply, your supervisor has to be a
qualified patent attorney or a barrister or solicitor with a history
of experience in patent attorney work. On completion of supervised
practice and exams, you can continue on to becoming a patent attorney.

Register with the IPRB

On passing your exams, you can complete registration with the IPRB to
operate as a qualified patent attorney. To register, you complete your
two years of supervised or four years of unsupervised practices and
meet all the requirements defined in the Patent Attorney and Trade
Mark Attorney Qualification and Registration Regulations 2009. Patent
attorneys pay practice fees to IPReg to maintain their status as
qualified patent attorneys.

Qualify as a European patent attorney

Many companies support international customers or have clients that
may require patent requirements from European countries as part of
their services. Qualifying as a European patent attorney requires
three years of training under a qualified professional. After
training, you complete the European Qualifying Examination. On passing
this exam, you can register with the Institute of Professional
Representatives before the European Patent Office (EPI).

